# Import Values of an Array into a Variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm very new in PHP or Programing at all and i have a problem which i can't solve alone.
I made a Test Website where i can upload songs (Filename = artist&song), and the uploaded songs are shown in a table with the artist.

So i created an array from my music folder where i uploaded my songs.

```
function displayfilename($artist, $song) {
$songarray = array_slice(scandir('music/mp3'), 2);
}
```

The Array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => hello&adele.mp3
[1] => hotline&drake.mp3
)
```

What i need to do is to save the first part of the value in a variable named $song and the second part of the value in a value named $artist, and then display them in a table (i guess with a for each).
I would appreciate it if you could try to help me with this problem^^

bye

Comment: Take a look at the `explode()` function. You could use `&` as delimiter

Answer (score 1):

Loop your `$songarray`, exploding your values by your separator, `&`

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($songarray as $sa)
{
    $exp = explode("&", $sa);
    $song = $exp[0]; $artist = $exp[1];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '    <td>' . $song . '</td>';
    echo '    <td>' . $artist . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```